# Reliable way to run code against Entities just Inserted with ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have some code that needs to run every time an Entity is Inserted into my database, the problem is that this code requires the Entity PrimaryKey.
I have found that I can get the Entities from the ObjectStateManager with EntityState.Unchanged and that is my object after Insert, but I am not sure if that will always be the only objects with "Unchanged" as their EntityState in the ObjectContext.

Is there a reliable way to run code only against objects that have JUST been Inserted with ObjectContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. You must call overloaded `SaveChanges` which will not accept changes after saving automatically and instead you will be responsible for calling `AcceptAllChanges`. In this scenario objects will be still in Added state after calling `SaveChanges` (but only till you call `AcceptAllChanges`). The general code should look like:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(...))
{
    context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);

    // Run your code here

    context.AcceptAllChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Transaction scope is not necessary - it is just example of the approach if you post insert code must run in the transaction with insertion.

You can also wrap that code into overriden `SaveChanges` so you will have it in centralized place.